# How to increase the image size in a GridView?

Tags: android, android-gridview

I have an array that successfully places 15 images into a GridView. However the Images are all very small when shown in the grid. How do I go about changing the size of them?
I have tried to change the GridView.LayoutParams to (100, 100) but there did not appear to be a change.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
    imageView.setImageResource(mThumbIds[position]);
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
    return imageView;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to make an adjustment based on the pixel density of a device o an emulator

```
DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
switch(metrics.densityDpi){
     case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_LOW:
                imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(lowVal, lowVal));
                break;
     case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_MEDIUM:
                imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(medVal, medVal));
                break;
     case DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_HIGH:
                 imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(highVal, highVal));
                 break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to change this:

```
imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
```

To this:

```
imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
```

You can set it to FIT_XY as well, but it introduces distortion.

Hope that helps